# std::bind to a std::variant containing multiple std::function types

Tags: c++, c++17, std-function, std-variant

I'm playing around with callback functions and wish to register multiple functions via `std::bind` that differ in signatures (altough they all return `void`). Assigning the result of the `std::bind` to the `std::variant` yields in a "conversion to non-scalar type" error. Is it an ambiguity error? Can I provide the compiler with more information?

Dropping the `std::bind` (which allows the assignment) is not an option as I wish to register the callbacks using some

```cpp
template <typename Function, typename... Args>
void register(Function &&f, Args &&... args)
{
    variant_of_multiple_func_types = std::bind(f, args...);
}
```

---

For example:

```cpp
std::variant<std::function<void()>, int> v = std::bind([]() noexcept {});
```

works, but

```cpp
std::variant<std::function<void()>, std::function<void(int)>> v = std::bind([]() noexcept {});
```

does not, while I expect it to compile into a `std::variant` containing a `std::function<void()>`.

I get the following compilation error in GCC 7.4.0 with `-std=c++17`:

```
error: conversion from ‘std::_Bind_helper<false, main(int, char**)::<lambda()> >::type {aka std::_Bind<main(int, char**)::<lambda()>()>}’ to non-scalar type ‘std::variant<std::function<void()>, std::function<void(int)> >’ requested
     std::variant<std::function<void()>, std::function<void(int)>> v = std::bind([]() noexcept {});
```

Comment: On a semi-related note: why must `noexcept` be specified for the lambda in the working example for compilation to pass?

Comment: Could you explain what you by "why must `noexcept` be specified for the lambda in the working example"?. Omitting the `noexcept` still works for me using the same compiler and flags.

Comment: why are you using `std::bind` with lambda? `std::bind` was useful when lambda could not be used. In your code `std::bind` is just obsolete.

Comment: `std::bind([]() noexcept {})("lot", "of", "unused", "parameter")` is valid. you can pass any number of parameter to the bind object, it is mostly needed for the `place_holder` (`std::bind([](int) {/*..*/}, place_holder::_5)`).

Comment: @Jonas, Oops, I missed that I had most warnings enabled. Compilation fails because `-Werror=noexcept` is specified.

Comment: @MarekR, I use `std::bind` with lambdas for brevity. In actual code I would only use it here inside the templated `register` function.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can using c++20 [`std::bind_front`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind_front) and it will compile:

```
#include <functional>
#include <variant>

int main()
{
    std::variant<std::function<void()>, std::function<void(int)>> v = std::bind_front([]() noexcept {});
    std::get<std::function<void()>>(v)();
}
```

[Live demo](https://godbolt.org/z/Uj_v1K)

According to [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind_front):

> This function is intended to replace `std::bind`. Unlike `std::bind`, it does not support arbitrary argument rearrangement and has no special treatment for nested bind-expressions or `std::reference_wrapper`s. On the other hand, it pays attention to the value category of the call wrapper object and propagates exception specification of the underlying call operator.

Comment: Jason Turner recently discussed his attempts at reimplementing `bind_front` in episodes [174](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7pqPfQ_HpmI), [177](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fLeHy7s1WIo), and [181](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s2Kqcn5e73c) of _C++ Weekly_. Might be interesting in lieu of C++20 availability.

Comment: It's weird to use `bind_front` in a situation where we're intentionally not taking any extra arguments. We're using `bind_front(f)` where `f` would work fine.

Answer (score 9):

`std::bind` returns an unspecified object that satisfies certain requirements, but doesn't allow for a distinction between function types based on a signature. The initialization

```
std::variant<std::function<void()>, std::function<void(int)>> v =
    std::bind([]() noexcept {});
```

is simply ambiguous, same as

```
std::variant<int, int> v = 42; // Error, don't know which one
```

You can be explicit about the type you intend to instantiate, e.g.

```
std::variant<std::function<void()>, std::function<void(int)>> v =
    std::function<void()>{std::bind([]() noexcept {})};
```

This cries for some type aliases, but basically works. A better alternative might be to avoid `std::bind` and instead use lambdas, too. Example:

```
template <typename Function, typename... Args>
void registerFunc(Function &&f, Args &&... args)
{
    variant_of_multiple_func_types =
       [&](){ std::forward<Function>(f)(std::forward<Args>(args)...); };
}
```

Answer (score 4):

One of the features of the `std::bind` is what it does with *extra* arguments. Consider:

```
int f(int i) { return i + 1; }
auto bound_f = std::bind(f, 42);
```

`bound_f()` invokes `f(42)` which gives `43`. But it is *also* the case that `bound_f("hello")` and `bound_f(2.0, '3', std::vector{4, 5, 6})` gives you `43`. All arguments on the call site that don't have an associated placeholder are ignored.

The significance here is that `is_invocable<decltype(bound_f), Args...>` is true for all sets of types `Args...`

---

Getting back to your example:

```
std::variant<std::function<void()>, std::function<void(int)>> v =
    std::bind([]() noexcept {});
```

The bind on the right works a lot like `bound_f` earlier. It's invocable with *any* set of arguments. It is invocable with no arguments (i.e. it is convertible to `std::function<void()>`) and it is invocable with an `int` (i.e. it is convertible to `std::function<void(int)>`). That is, both alternatives of the variant can be constructed from the bind expression, and we have no way of distinguishing one from the other. They're both just conversions.  Hence, ambiguous.

We would *not* have this problem with lambdas:

```
std::variant<std::function<void()>, std::function<void(int)>> v =
    []() noexcept {};
```

This works fine, because that lambda is only invocable with no arguments, so only one alternative is viable. Lambdas don't just drop unused arguments.

This generalizes to:

```
template <typename Function, typename... Args>
void register(Function &&f, Args &&... args)
{
    variant_of_multiple_func_types =
        [f=std::forward<Function>(f), args=std::make_tuple(std::forward<Args>(args)...)]{
            return std::apply(f, args);
        });
}
```

Though if you want to actually pass placeholders here, this won't work. It really depends on your larger design what the right solution here might be.

Answer (score -1):

The reason is that the `std::bind` results in a different type (it's an unspecified / Callable type) than `std::function`- so while convertible - it's ambiguous.